# Insert new line after a particular line in batch file using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to insert a line in a batch file after a particular line.
Input:

```
set MTBBankpath=C:\InstallerOutput\QuickBooks-Sync\MTB
echo To copy QuickBooks-Sync COM components into resultant folder
copy /Y %ConnectorExecutionPath%\%outqbsyncpath%
```

Output:

```
set MTBBankpath=C:\InstallerOutput\QuickBooks-Sync\MTB
set IndbBankpath=C:\InstallerOutput\QuickBooks-Sync\indb
echo To copy QuickBooks-Sync COM components into resultant folder
copy /Y %ConnectorExecutionPath%\%outqbsyncpath%
```

A New line `set IndbBankpath=C:\InstallerOutput\QuickBooks-Sync\indb` get inserted after a particular line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set inputFile=%userprofile%\desktop\testSO.bat
set outputFile=%userprofile%\desktop\testSOout.bat
set _strInsert=set IndbBankpath=C:\InstallerOutput\QuickBooks-Sync\indb
set _strFind=set MTBBankpath=C:\InstallerOutput\QuickBooks-Sync\MTB

FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A IN ("%inputFile%") DO (
  Echo %%A | Find "%_strFind%" && ECHO %%A>>"%outputFile%" && ECHO %_strInsert%>>"%outputFile%"
  IF [!errorlevel!] == [1] ECHO %%A>>"%outputFile%"
)
```

Basically, for every line in the file, perform `FIND` on it for the string in question, and if it finds it, echo the string into the out file, and then echo what you want to insert into the outfile. If it doesn't find what you're looking for in that string, it will just echo the string into the out file.

EDIT: If the file is fairly large... this will probably be a little faster

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set inputFile=%userprofile%\desktop\testSO.bat
set outputFile=%userprofile%\desktop\testSOout.bat
set _strInsert=set IndbBankpath=C:\InstallerOutput\QuickBooks-Sync\indb
set _strFind=set MTBBankpath=C:\InstallerOutput\QuickBooks-Sync\MTB
set i=0

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1 delims=[]" %%A IN (`FIND /N "%_strFind%" "%inputFile%"`) DO (set _strNum=%%A)
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A IN ("%inputFile%") DO (
  set /a i = !i! + 1
  ECHO %%A>>"%outputFile%"
  IF [!i!] == [%_strNum%] (ECHO %_strInsert%>>"%outputFile%")
)
```

If you want to "pretend" it's writing to the same file, add this to the end of the script.

`MOVE /Y "%outputFile%" "%inputFile%" && DEL /F /Q "%outputFile%"`

EDIT: I CAN HAZ MORE LYNES!?

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

```
set inputFile=%userprofile%\desktop\testSO.bat
set outputFile=%userprofile%\desktop\testSOout.bat
set _strInsert=set IndbBankpath=C:\InstallerOutput\QuickBooks-Sync\indb
set _strFind=set MTBBankpath=C:\InstallerOutput\QuickBooks-Sync\MTB
set i=0

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1 delims=[]" %%A IN (`FIND /N "%_strFind%" "%inputFile%"`) DO (set _strNum=%%A)
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A IN ("%inputFile%") DO (
  set /a i = !i! + 1
  ECHO %%A>>"%outputFile%"
  IF [!i!] == [%_strNum%] (
    ECHO %_strInsert%>>"%outputFile%"
    ECHO I WANT TO ADD THIS LINE ALSO>>"%outputFile%"
    ECHO OOOO THIS LiNE TOO>>"%outputFile%"
    ECHO ZOMGBBQSAUCE ADD THIS LINE ALSO>>"%outputFile%"
  )
)
```

Comment: If I want to add two or three lines after a particular line,Wat can be done.

Comment: you don't code much do you? lol.  I'll add an edit in a minute.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.Execution stops with "Missing operator."

Comment: noticed the error: `ECHO %%A>>%"outputFile%"` should be `ECHO %%A>>"%outputFile%"`

Comment: I can able to insert a line which doesn't have any command like mkdir or copy. If I try to insert a line "mkdir %ConnectorExecutionPath%\QuickBooks-Sync\obj\x86\Release", it fails..Cos mkdir is not considered as a word rather it is considered as command.. Hope, you can help me out...

Comment: this should be created as a separate question cause now you're running into a different problem.