# Insert new lines(which has a command) after a particular line in batch file using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to insert a line which has a command(mkdir/copy) in a batch file after a particular line using a batch file.(mkdir/copy command should be considered as a word rather than command)
Input:

> set MTBBankpath=C:\InstallerOutput\QuickBooks-Sync\MTB
>   copy /Y %QBprovisionpath%\x86\Debug %ConnectorExecutionPath%\x86\Debug

Output:

> set MTBBankpath=C:\InstallerOutput\QuickBooks-Sync\MTB
>   copy /Y %ConnectorExecutionPath%\%outqbsyncpath%
>   mkdir /Y %ConnectorExecutionPath%\%outqbsyncpath%
>   copy /Y %QBprovisionpath%\x86\Debug %ConnectorExecutionPath%\x86\Debug

A New line **copy /Y %ConnectorExecutionPath%\%outqbsyncpath%** - which has a copy command and **mkdir /Y %ConnectorExecutionPath%\%outqbsyncpath%** which has mkdir command, get inserted after a particular line **set MTBBankpath=C:\InstallerOutput\QuickBooks-Sync\MTB**

> SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
>
> set inputFile=%userprofile%\desktop\testSO.bat
>   set outputFile=%userprofile%\desktop\testSOout.bat
>   set _strInsert=set IndbBankpath=C:\InstallerOutput\QuickBooks-Sync\indb
>   set _strFind=set MTBBankpath=C:\InstallerOutput\QuickBooks-Sync\MTB
>   set i=0
>
> FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1 delims=[]" %%A IN (`FIND /N "%_strFind%" "%inputFile%"`) DO (set _strNum=%%A)
>   FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A IN ("%inputFile%") DO (
>    set /a i = !i! + 1
>    ECHO %%A>>"%outputFile%"
>   IF [!i!] == [%_strNum%] (
>     ECHO %_strInsert%>>"%outputFile%"
>    ECHO I WANT TO ADD THIS LINE ALSO>>"%outputFile%"
>     ECHO OOOO THIS LiNE TOO>>"%outputFile%"
>    ECHO ZOMGBBQSAUCE ADD THIS LINE ALSO>>"%outputFile%"
>   )
>   )

The above code doesn't work if I change 
 **set _strInsert=copy /Y %ConnectorExecutionPath%\%outqbsyncpath%** or 
**set _strInsert=mkdir %ConnectorExecutionPath%\%outqbsyncpath%**

Please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: What "particular line" means to you? The line number 1? The line with certain contents? In this case, which contents?

Comment: the line with certain contents.I have to search for a particular line like "set MTBBankpath=C:\InstallerOutput\QuickBooks-Sync\MTB",I have to insert the new lines after that line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert new line after a particular line in batch file using batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288855/insert-new-line-after-a-particular-line-in-batch-file-using-batch-file)

Comment: No,that is for inserting a line without commands.

Comment: Sorry, I fail to understand how this question is different from your similar question of a week ago.

Comment: @Gabe - If you try inserting a line which has a command like "mkdir",mkdir is considered as a command rather than just word.I just want to insert a line "mkdir ...",but when I execute the batch file to insert a line, it started executing the command "mkdir" in that line which is to inserted.Understood?

Comment: @Ramya: You have to post the code that doesn't work so we can see where it went wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the only problem you're running into is the fact that you're not encapsulating your paths for the `COPY` and `MKDIR` commands:

`set _strInsert=mkdir %ConnectorExecutionPath%\%outqbsyncpath%`

Try:

`set _strInsert=mkdir "%ConnectorExecutionPath%\%outqbsyncpath%"`

I would also do a check for the folder before creating it as well.

EDIT:

Now if you're adding in a bunch of different lines, just add them to the code. In your previous post you asked to add a single line to the code. If you're doing multiple lines, just echo them directly into the output file.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set inputFile=%userprofile%\desktop\testSO.bat
set outputFile=%userprofile%\desktop\testSOout.bat
set _strFind=set MTBBankpath=C:\InstallerOutput\QuickBooks-Sync\MTB
set i=0

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1 delims=[]" %%A IN (FIND /N "%_strFind%" "%inputFile%") DO (set _strNum=%%A)
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A IN ("%inputFile%") DO (
    set /a i = !i! + 1
    ECHO %%A>>"%outputFile%"
    IF [!i!] == [%_strNum%] (
        ECHO set IndbBankpath=C:\InstallerOutput\QuickBooks-Sync\indb
        ECHO copy /Y "%ConnectorExecutionPath%\%outqbsyncpath%"
        ECHO mkdir /Y "%ConnectorExecutionPath%\%outqbsyncpath%"
        ECHO copy /Y "%QBprovisionpath%\x86\Debug %ConnectorExecutionPath%\x86\Debug"
    )>>"%outputFile%"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
set "particularLine=set MTBBankpath=C:\InstallerOutput\QuickBooks-Sync\MTB"
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
if exist output.bat del output.bat
for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.bat) do (
   echo %%a
   set "line=%%a"
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   if "!line!" == "!particularLine!" (
      echo copy /Y %%ConnectorExecutionPath%%\%%outqbsyncpath%%
      echo mkdir /Y %%ConnectorExecutionPath%%\%%outqbsyncpath%%
   )
   endlocal
) >> output.bat
```

Previous Batch file has several drawbacks: it remove empty lines and may fail if the line contain quotes.

**EDIT**: *New version added*

The Batch file below run faster if the input file is large; it also have several details fixed, like not removing empty lines.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "inputFile=%userprofile%\desktop\testSO.bat"
set "outputFile=%userprofile%\desktop\testSOout.bat"
set "particularLine=set MTBBankpath=C:\InstallerOutput\QuickBooks-Sync\MTB"
for /F "usebackq delims=:" %%a in (`findstr /N /C:"!particularLine!" "%inputFile%"`) do set theLine=%%a
if exist "%outputFile%" del "%outputFile%"
if not defined theLine echo The particular line doesn't exist in Input file & exit /B
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set i=0
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`findstr /N "^" "%inputFile%"`) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   set /A i+=1
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   echo(!line:*:=!
   if !i! eql %theLine% goto exitLoop
   endlocal
) >> "%outputFile%"
:exitLoop
rem Insert here all the lines to insert, each one preceeded by ECHO
(
   echo copy /Y "%%ConnectorExecutionPath%%\%%outqbsyncpath%%"
   echo mkdir /Y "%%ConnectorExecutionPath%%\%%outqbsyncpath%%"
) >> "%outputFile%"
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "skip=%theLine% usebackq delims=" %%a in (`findstr /N "^" "%inputFile%"`) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   echo(!line:*:=!
   endlocal
) >> "%outputFile%"
```

Please note that you must double the percent signs in the commands to insert; otherwise what is inserted is the *current value* of the variables instead of the %name% of the variables.

Comment: i don't see how my batch script would remove empty lines and fail on quotes? =(

Comment: @Mechaflash - both you code and Aacini's code will strip blank lines because FOR /F strips blank lines. Your FIND command could fail if your search string contains quotes.

Comment: i see... i didn't know of either of those issues.

Comment: @Mechaflash - in my previous comment to you, replace you(r) with OP. I thought you were the OP, sorry.